Is upstream config bidirectional on Address Federation with Symetric Topology between 2 clusters?
I have 2 ActiveMQ Artemis clusters with 3 nodes each. One is running in Europe and the other is running in the USA. Now I want to activate the Address Federation like in the documentation.
I've already set it up, but I'm receiving duplicated messages (I think is always 2). I did not understood if when we set the upstream federation Europe -> USA, it is bidirectional or unidirectional (from Fan Out and Ring it seems unidirectional), so I've also set it up an upstream federation from USA -> Europe.
Can this be the cause for the duplicates? On both sides the max-hops is set to 1, as documentation states:

In this setup, it is important to set max-hops=1, so messages are copied only once and cyclic replication is avoided. If max-hops is not configured correctly, consumers will get multiple copies of the same message.

I want the federation because I want to shift all producers and consumers from Europe to the  USA in small steps.
Here are the configuration for node 3 (1 and 2 are the same, only the artemis connector changes on each one.) on each geo site:
Node 3 (Europe)
<connectors>
    <!-- Connector used to be announced through cluster connections and notifications -->
    <connector name="artemis">tcp://dev-broker-europe-03.example.com:61616?sslEnabled=true</connector>

    <connector name="usa-01-connector">tcp://dev-broker-usa-01.example.com:61616</connector>
    <connector name="usa-02-connector">tcp://dev-broker-usa-02.example.com:61616</connector>
    <connector name="usa-03-connector">tcp://dev-broker-usa-03.example.com:61616</connector>
</connectors>

<federations>
    <federation name="europe-dev" user="usa-federation-user" password="*******">
        <upstream name="usa-dev">
            <static-connectors>
                <connector-ref>usa-01-connector</connector-ref>
                <connector-ref>usa-02-connector</connector-ref>
                <connector-ref>usa-03-connector</connector-ref>
            </static-connectors>
            <policy ref="events-federation"/>
        </upstream>

        <address-policy name="events-federation" max-hops="1" auto-delete="true" auto-delete-delay="300000" auto-delete-message-count="-1">
            <include address-match="events.#" />
        </address-policy>
    </federation>
</federations>

Node 3 (USA)
<connectors>
    <!-- Connector used to be announced through cluster connections and notifications -->
    <connector name="artemis">tcp://dev-broker-usa-03.example.com:61616?sslEnabled=true</connector>

    <connector name="europe-01-connector">tcp://dev-broker-europe-01.example.com:61616?sslEnabled=true</connector>
    <connector name="europe-02-connector">tcp://dev-broker-europe-02.example.com:61616?sslEnabled=true</connector>
    <connector name="europe-03-connector">tcp://dev-broker-europe-03.example.com:61616?sslEnabled=true</connector>
</connectors>

<federations>
    <federation name="usa-dev" user="europe-federation-user" password="*******">
        <upstream name="europe-dev">
            <static-connectors>
                <connector-ref>europe-01-connector</connector-ref>
                <connector-ref>europe-02-connector</connector-ref>
                <connector-ref>europe-03-connector</connector-ref>
            </static-connectors>
            <policy ref="events-federation"/>
        </upstream>

        <address-policy name="events-federation" max-hops="1" auto-delete="true" auto-delete-delay="300000" auto-delete-message-count="-1">
            <include address-match="events.#" />
        </address-policy>
    </federation>
</federations>

Currently I only have a consumer in USA that subscribes to events.#, and when messages are produced in Europe it receives duplicates that are not persisted because there's an unique constraint in the database.
Disabling the federation from Europe side stops the duplicates on the consumer that is in USA. But for a smooth transition of consumers and producers from Europe to USA I need federation on both sides so that a producer in Europe can produce to Europe consumers and also USA and vice-versa.

currently in USA I only have a consumer that matches any address (something like: events.#). There I've seen duplicates that are prevented as I have a unique constraint for the message id. I think (not 100% sure) I've also observed duplicates in Europe, i.e. I have consumer and producer for topic events.abc and the consumer would receive the message twice. It's like the message is going to USA (1 hop) and then back to Europe (1 hop) because they are 2 federations and the hops are counted by name (Not sure it works like that)

you should provide more details on your exact federation configuration in the question to allow for deeper analysis

Agree. Added the configuration for node 3. The other are the same, only the artemis connector changes on each one.

Disabling the federation from Europe side stops the duplicates on the consumer that is in USA. But for a smooth transition of consumer and producers from Europe to USA I need both side federation, so a producer in Europe can produce to Europe consumers and also USA and vice-versa.

This seems to boil down to configuration related questions vs actual software development or programming related so likely you'd be better served asking this in the ActiveMQ community

So instead of having  we changed it to have , lucky all topics share the .abc part and therefore was simple. This fixed the duplicates. Duplicates were caused due the consumer in USA that subscribed to events.# created a topic that matched exactly the federations so it was sending back the same message.

Then we had a problem with message acknowledges, that my colleague send to the user community and you have answered https://lists.apache.org/thread/xgtb600pbmxht61hjs8hxl5k1cg21kv2. So now everything seems to work fine.
